# How do I reflectively invoke a method with null as argument?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to invoke this method in Java reflectively:

```
public void setFoo(ArrayList<String> foo) { this.foo = foo; }
```

The problem is that I want to pass null as `null`, so that foo becomes null.

However, in the following approach it assumes that there are no arguments, and I get `IllegalArgumentException`(`wrong number of arguments`):

```
method.invoke(new FooHolder(), null);
// -----------------------------^ - I want null to be passed to the method...
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: When `varargs` turn bad.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try

```
method.invoke(new FooHolder(), new Object[]{ null });
```

Comment: thanks, but why can an object array with single item (null item) replace a null object?
new Object[]{null} == null?
That new to me. Can someone explain it for me? Thanks

Comment: thanks, but why can an object array with single item (null item) replace a null object?
new Object[]{null} == null?
That new to me. Can someone explain it for me? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I got it, the arguments with 3 dots: Object... args -> is equivalent to Object array.

Comment: For those who use Groovy: use [null].toArray()

Comment: For me it didn't work with primitive types

Comment: And if you want it to work for any number of parameters you can just go:
`method.invoke(new FooHolder(), new Object[method.getParameterCount()]);`

Answer (score 8):

For me, this DOES NOT work:

> m.invoke ( c.newInstance() , new Object[] { null } );

BUT this works:

> m.invoke ( c.newInstance() , new Object[] {  } );

Comment: Then maybe you've got a method with no arguments

Answer (score 7):

The compiler warning should make you aware of the problem;

> The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to Object[] for
>   the invocation of the varargs method invoke(Object, Object...) from
>   type Method. It could alternatively be cast to Object for a varargs
>   invocation

You can fix it like this;

```
Object arg = null;
method.invoke(new FooHolder(), arg);
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit of an explanation to the solutions already posted.

`Method.invoke()` is declared as a variable arity function, and that means that normally you don't need to explicitly create an object array. Only because you pass a single parameter, which could be interpreted as an object array itself, does `method.invoke( obj, null)` fail.

If for example your method had two parameters, `method.invoke( obj, null, null)` would work perfectly fine.

However if your method has a single `Object[]` parameter, you always have to wrap it.