# How get method with List<SomeObject> as parameter using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have

```
public void setContacts(List<PersonContact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
```

A need get this method using Reflection, I have tried

```
  clazz.getMethod("setContacts", ArrayList.class);
```

show the erro :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.person.Person.setContacts(java.util.ArrayList)
```

That's correct, the method signature is

```
    setContacts(List<PersonContact> contacts)
```

So, how can I pass correct signature in getMethod?

Comment: Use `List.class`. Why are you using `ArrayList.class`?

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection for this task? Just curious...

Comment: How should it distinguish between `setContacts(List<PersonContact> contacts)` and `setContacts(List<String> contacts)` (if such a method exists).

Comment: @crush Such a method cannot exist in the same class. They would have the same erasure.

Comment: @crush  I need to serialize to JSON objects retrieved from database, these objects has List, I dont want serialize these list and I cannot use JsonIgnore annotation in the pojos,  to avoid LazyInitializationException during serialization, I just set null to List properties

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the term - need to look into that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the parameter type is `java.util.List` and not `java.util.ArrayList`

```
clazz.getMethod("setContacts", List.class);
```

It is important that you uses the actual class because you could also have the method overloaded with an ArrayList parameter

Comment: OK, it works, I get method without error, but if I try  method.invoke(personObject, null); show the error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

I just want to exec setContacts(null); using reflection

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Cast the `null` to `Object`.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087989/how-do-i-reflectively-invoke-a-method-with-null-as-argument might help you